# Steps to convert a new xcode cocoa project using 1 controller per nib

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, model-view-controller

I want to start off my new xcode project using 1 nib per controller.  By default it seems xcode creates:

```
1. delegate .h/.m
2. MainMenu.xib
```

And looking at the targets for the project, I see that the 'main nib file base name' is set to MainMenu, the principal class is NSApplication.

Since cocoa is MVC based, how are things MVC based on the default template?

How can I wire things together with a 'MainWindowController' instead of this default setup?  **If someone can explain the steps to me that would be much appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to subvert or change the default setup, just to understand it and work within it. `MVC` is a description of responsibility rather than some hard requirement about naming.

The `delegate .h/.m` is the app delegate by name, but its responsibility is to be the app controller. It gets everything setup when the app starts and deals with application level events. It shouldn't do anything that isn't related to application level management.

The `MainMenu.xib` is just a container / archive of the first Views and Controllers that are to be created when the application opens.

There is no Model in the template really as all it does is display the main window with a static string on it...

Your goal of `using 1 nib per controller` is fine, but you should be a little flexible with the naming at first. Because the `MainMenu.xib` contains the main window it should also contain your MainWindowController. This is perfect from an MVC point of view because you are separating the responsibility.

Then, your future Controllers and Views (in their XIBs) can have matching names to keep everything clear. And you can created your Model separately.